# Sending message from chrome extension to every newly opened tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, async-await, tabs, messaging

I'm trying to send a message - using chrome.tabs.sendMessage - to every tab that gets opened. The problem is that chrome.tabs.query and sendMessage don't want to work well with options such as chrome.tabs.onCreated. I think this is because those functions are asynchronous, but everything I've tried with that in mind has failed so far. Does anyone have any solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, you need to use an API event like chrome.tabs.onCreated. Second, there may be a better approach, so add a description of what you want to implement.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.